# Mobile command button issue

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

In the iPhone ADF mobile app I have a textinput field  and a "Save" commandbutton. In the properties for the commandbutton I have the disabled condition set (like if the textinput field is null). This works fine. In the beginning the save button is disabled and when I enter any text with a keyboard the button is automatically enabled and vice versa.

The only issue is my users can enter the text via voice too. If they use the voice to fill the text field - still the save button is not enabled. As soon as they change anything using key board it is enabled.

How do I set the command button properties to check this please?

Answer (score 0):

In the InputText properties there is a property called Value Change Listener,
add a java method to it to check if the value is null or not then try one of the below:

1. Reset the InputText value as this will fire the propertyChangeListner and may activate your button.
2. Disable or Enable your button in code according to the value.

Hope this help.